# How to subscribe to a platform event just once per page load?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, platform-event

I have some code that works fine, the subscription works well, and the code functions as expected, too. The problem occurs when I switch lightning tabs and go back to the lightning tab with my component. Since my subscription occurs in the init function, each time it loads it subscribes. This isn't a problem when its the only tab in a lightning app and can only be subscribed once, but with multiple tabs, the component not only makes duplicate events due to multiple subscriptions, but it also throws a callback error.

[image]

How can I, if possible, make it so that the subscription occurs once per page load instead of per component initialization (I still want it to be automated, i.e. no button)?

Here's some of my relevant code:

EventListener.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="CounterController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>
    <aura:attribute name="records" type="CounterController.CounterWrapper[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="liveStream" type="CounterController.StreamWrapper"/>
    <aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="/event/Status_Change__e"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="UpdateVisual" type="c:UpdateVisual"/>
    <aura:handler name="UpdateVisual" event="c:UpdateVisual" action="{!c.createItemDynamically}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.NoHeader}"/>

    <div class="connect slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_info" role="alert">
        <b>Waiting to connect...</b>
    </div>
    <div class="done slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_info" style="display: none; background-color:green;" role="alert">
        <b>Connected!</b>
    </div>
    <div class="error slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_warning" style="display: none;" role="alert">
        <b>You may need to refresh the page...</b>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-var-p-around_small slds-size_6-of-12">
            <lightning:datatable
                keyField="id"
                data="{! v.records }"
                columns="{! v.columns }"
                hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        </div>
        <div aura:id="divBody" style="background-color: #eaeaea;" class="slds-box slds-col slds-var-p-around_small slds-size_6-of-12">
            <label style="padding-bottom: 5px; margin: 0 auto;" class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_medium slds-border_bottom" for="form-element-01"><b>Livestream</b> </label>
            <ul aura:id="log" style="padding-top: 5px;" class="slds-has-dividers_around-space">
                {!v.body}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

EventListenerController.js

```
onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getRecords(component)

    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'API Name', fieldName: 'apiName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Success Count', fieldName: 'sCount', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Failure Count', fieldName: 'fCount', type: 'number'},
    ]);

    window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
        var action2 = component.get('c.handleEmpApi')
        action2.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("connect");
                elements[0].style.display = 'none';
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("done");
                elements[0].style.display = 'block';
                window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
                    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("done");
                    elements[0].style.display = 'none';
                }), 1500);
            }else{
                console.log('Failed with state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);
    }), 2000);
},
handleEmpApi : function (component, event, helper){
    const empApi = component.find('empApi');

    empApi.onError($A.getCallback(error => {
        console.error(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
        if(error.channel == '/meta/subscribe'){

        }else if(error.error == "401::Authentication invalid" || error.advice.reconnect == "none"){
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("done");
            elements[0].style.display = 'none';
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
            elements[0].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }));

    helper.subscribe(component, event, helper);
}
```

EventListenerHelper.js

```
subscribe: function (component, event, helper) {

    const empApi = component.find('empApi');
    const channel = component.get('v.channel');
    const replayId = -1;
    const callback = function (message) {
        var data = message.data;
        window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
            helper.getRecords(component)
            window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
                helper.updateStream(component, data);
            }), 500);    
        }), 750);
    };

    empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(callback)).then($A.getCallback(function (newSubscription) {
        console.log('Subscribed to channel ' + channel);
        component.set('v.subscription', newSubscription);
    }));
}
```

EDIT

Error is same as above, code is as follows:

Error occurs in EventListenerHelper.js in callback

```
helper.getRecords(component)
```

Here is getRecords method (also in helper):

```
getRecords : function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.getAPIDetails')
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                component.set('v.liveStream', response.getReturnValue());
                var action2 = component.get('c.getResults')
                action2.setCallback(this, function(response){
                    var state = response.getState();
                    if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                        component.set('v.records', response.getReturnValue());
                    }else{
                        console.log('Failed with state: ' + state);
                    }
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(action2);
            }else{
                console.log('Failed with state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: is it console tab or browser tab?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was a bit unclear, console, within the Salesforce lightning app itself, changing THOSE tabs back and forth.

Comment: Sorry I meant is the app in lightning console

Comment: Yes, the app is a tab in the lightning console and the component is in the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!window.subscribed) {
    helper.subscribe(component, event, helper);
    window.subscribed = true;
}
```

Actually it would be better if you use **window.subscribed = true;** in success callback of subscription.

Comment: But that will make it just one Subtab can subscribe to events in lightning console app?

Comment: So, it doesn't resubscribe, as noted, but the error still occurs, will update the post with exact source code where the error is happening

Comment: Ok, so I found out a solution to my problem, if I could, I would like to edit this as it helped me get to my solution. The error was that it needed to resubscribe each time because the component id was different each time, so you just had to erase the old subscription, and create a new one. Didn't know you could just add elements to the window until now either. Thanks!